# Apache Camel No type converter available

Tags: java, apache-camel, quarkus

I defined a processor with camel which allow me to generate a jaxb java bean with a timer and write the pojo in xml file.
But when I launch the application I got the following error:

08:09:00 WARN  [or.ap.ca.co.ti.TimerConsumer] (Camel (camel-1) thread #2 - timer://generateInvoice) Error processing exchange. Exchange[20E715FDB7EFE19-0000000000000000]. Caused by: [java.io.IOException - org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException: No type converter available to convert from type: java.util.LinkedList to the required type: java.io.InputStream with value [com.mycompany.model.Invoice@21e27bf, com.mycompany.model.Invoice@1fd7b4bf, com.mycompany.model.Invoice@9cb7bae, com.mycompany.model.Invoice@2751bc51 ...

My code is bellow:

```
from("timer:generateInvoice?period={{xml.timer.period}}&delay={{xml.timer.delay}}")
        .log("Generating randomized invoice XML data")
        .process("invoiceGenerator")
        .marshal(jaxbDataFormat)
        .to("file:{{xml.location}}");
```

Bellow my generator:

```
@Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

        Random random = new Random();
        List<Invoice> invoices = new LinkedList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

            String invoiceNumber = String.format("invoice-%d", random.nextInt());

            Invoice invoice = new Invoice();
            invoice.setInvoiceNumber(invoiceNumber);
            invoice.setAmount(random.nextDouble());

            Instant now = Instant.now();

            GregorianCalendar cal1 = new GregorianCalendar();
            cal1.setTimeInMillis(now.toEpochMilli());
            invoice.setInsertionDate(DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar());
            invoice.setInvoiceType(INVOICE_TYPE[random.nextInt(INVOICE_TYPE.length)]);
            invoices.add(invoice);
        }
        exchange.getMessage().setBody(invoices);
    }
```

I already tried to implement a converter of java.util.LinkedList to the required type: java.io.InputStream

with:

```
@Converter
    public InputStream ListToInputStream(List<Invoice> invoices) throws IOException {

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ByteArrayInputStream bios = null;
            try {

                ObjectFactory objFactory = new ObjectFactory();

                JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.webinage.model");
                Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
                marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);

                for(Invoice invoice : invoices) {
                    marshaller.marshal(invoice, baos);
                }
                bios = new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[baos.size()]);
                bios.read(baos.toByteArray());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                baos.close();
            }
            return bios;
    }
```

But same exception rise up ...
do you have an idea plz ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably List is not what you want to put into the Exchange. I assume you want output XML to be something like:

```
<Invoices>
 <Invoice>...</Invoice>
 <Invoice>...</Invoice>
 ...
</Invoices>
```

in which case it's probably most straightforward to declare a container class:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Invoices {
  private List<Invoice> invoices;
}
```

(getter and setter omitted).

Then generate your schema and put this `Invoices` object into the Exchange.

Comment: Szymanski, thank a lot but now I have another error (not really according to this post, it that why I create a new in order to decorrelate the problem): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71189622/how-to-fix-camel-jaxb-unmasharlling-problem